# What to do if you have wronged someone and never got the chance to apologize to them?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

When I was younger I accused a Christian girl in my class for kissing another girl even though I didn't see her do it, and she got in trouble for it. I don't know if they believed her when she said she didn't do it or not and I don't know how it and if it effected her. I grew up and now I feel so horrible for that and I want to apologize to her but the thing is that she left the school and I also changed school and now I have no idea where she is and I can't apologize to her. What do I do? Should I ask for forgiveness or will I not be forgiven at all? Or should I make dua for her? Because one of the major sins is accusing a chaste woman of Zina and I did that when I had no idea and I regret it now
I'm also worried if I have caused problems in her family because of this

Comment: Accusing of kissing is not accusing of zina. Indeed you should repent and ask for forgiveness

Answer (score 1):

Aslam Walaykum

If you did not have the chance to apologize to her, then instead you should ask Allah to forgive you and make dua for her, that way allah the most forgiving will forgive you. Allah is the most merciful, so do not worry. :)